# Просмотр таблицы в pysnmp

Tags: python, snmp

Цель - хочу просмотреть выбрать мак-адреса из таблицы snmp.

```
cmdGen = cmdgen.CommandGenerator()
cmdGen.ignoreNonIncreasingOid = True
errorIndication, errorStatus, errorIndex, \
                 varBindTable = cmdGen.nextCmd(
    cmdgen.CommunityData(community, community),
    cmdgen.UdpTransportTarget((hostname, 161)),
    dot1dTpFdbTable
    )
    for varBindTableRow in varBindTable:
        for name, val in varBindTableRow:
```

Получаю varBindTableRow и кучу oid в несортированном виде. Хочется получить в итоге массив `arr[id](param1, param2, param3)`. Можно ли это сделать? Как?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
errorIndication, errorStatus, errorIndex,varBindTable = cmdgen.CommandGenerator().nextCmd(cmdgen.CommunityData('None','initial_pysnmp'),
cmdgen.UdpTransportTarget(('uvr-24',161)),(1,3,6,1,2,1,17,7,1,2,2,1,2))

for varBindTableRow in varBindTable:
    for name, val in varBindTableRow:
        vlan = "{0}".format(name[13])
        mac = "{0}:{1}:{2}:{3}:{4}:{5}".format(hex(name[14])[2:].zfill(2),hex(name[15])[2:].zfill(2),
                                                hex(name[16])[2:].zfill(2),hex(name[17])[2:].zfill(2),
                                                hex(name[18])[2:].zfill(2),hex(name[19])[2:].zfill(2))
        port = "{0}:{1}".format(int(val.prettyPrint())/64+1,int(val.prettyPrint())%64)
        print vlan,mac,port

        999 00:1c:f0:06:44:d7 1:26
        999 00:1c:f0:0d:29:15 1:26
        999 00:1c:f0:1a:b9:e5 1:26
```