# Как преобразовать ответ на запрос в MAC устройства?

Tags: python, snmp

Приветствую!

Учусь Питону, возник вопрос с примером:

```
from pysnmp.entity.rfc3413.oneliner import cmdgen

errorIndication, errorStatus, errorIndex, varBinds = cmdgen.CommandGenerator().getCmd(cmdgen.CommunityData('my-agent', 'public', 0), cmdgen.UdpTransportTarget(('10.1.1.5', 161)), (1,3,6,1,2,1,2,2,1,6,3))

print errorIndication
print errorStatus
print varBinds
```

Когда запрашиваю имя устройства (oid 1,3,6,1,2,1,2,2,1,2,3), все ок: varBinds возвращает имя. Когда запрашиваю мак устройства (oid 1,3,6,1,2,1,2,2,1,6,3), то вместо мака varBinds возвращает:

> `None
> 0
> [(ObjectName('1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.6.1'), OctetString('\x00&Z\x8ah\x00'))]`

Как преобразовать это в мак?

Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как-то так:

```
mac = varBinds[0][1] # или где там у вас mac лежит?
print(':'.join(['%02x' % ord(x) for x in mac]))
```

Answer (score 1):

Посмотри ссылку [pysnmp](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/37251/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%80-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%8B-%D0%B2-pysnmp)